# Windows service bus 1.1: Add anonymous accessible namespace

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

Is it possible or do the clients have to use a shared access key or winauth to connect to the namespace?
Example: How do I create a namespace that I can connect to azure service bus explorer, without credentials?

Note that I mean namespace, not per queue or topics

Answer (score 3):

Winauth is the preferred method for controlling access on site. Any winauth user should be able to connect and see the queues/topics, but until granted permissions on the namespace or entity (queue/table) they can't actually do anything.  If you want to control access at the Namespace level, create an Active Directory group, assign users then create the namespace with that group as the manage user:

```
New-SBNamespace -Name MyNamespace1 -ManageUsers groupName@domain1
```

Read more about [Service Bus for Windows Server Authentication and Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441400.aspx).